# What is the keyboard shortcut to "replace next" in PyCharm?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pycharm

In PyCharm, what is the keyboard short-cut to replace the next occurrence of a word?
I know that `Ctrl+R` opens the dialogue to replace words, but is there a shortcut that actually does the replacing of the word, so I don't have to use the mouse to press the Replace button every time?

Comment: Did you try to press the Alt key to see the mnemonics? Alt+P is the mnemonic for Replace.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, the Alt key and Alt+P don't do anything in my PyCharm. I looked in the Keymap settings and the only relevant action is "replace", which is mapped to Ctrl+R here.

Comment: What OS do you use? See the File | Settings | Appearance, Disable mnemonics in controls must be off. When you press and hold Alt key, letters with mnemonics will be underlined: http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/3949/20121014162359.png.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, it works, Alt+P "presses" the Replace button after Ctrl+R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buttons/options of the **Replace** dialog can be accessed using mnemonics, press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to see them, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> will have the same effect as clicking on the **Replace** button.